# GameKit achievement notifications not showing up even though they were working before?

Tags: swift, game-center, gamekit

Yesterday I got Game Center notifications working for my achievements, but as soon as I tried them again today they didn't work? All I did was re-organise the code, and the achievements are going through to Game Center when you earn them. I cannot think of why my `submitAchievements()` function could be wrong, but I'll paste it here:

```
            GKAchievement.loadAchievements(completionHandler: { (achievements: [GKAchievement]?, error: Error?) in
                let fifteenID = "15"
                var fifteenAchievement: GKAchievement? = nil
                
                // Find an existing achievement.
                fifteenAchievement = achievements?.first(where: { $0.identifier == fifteenID})
                
                // Otherwise, create a new achievement.
                if fifteenAchievement == nil {
                    fifteenAchievement = GKAchievement(identifier: fifteenID)
                }
                
                if score >= 15 {
                    fifteenAchievement?.showsCompletionBanner = true
                    fifteenAchievement?.percentComplete = 100
                }
                
                // Insert code to report the percentage.
                
                if error != nil {
                    // Handle the error that occurs.
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                }
                
                let thirtyID = "30"
                var thirtyAchievement: GKAchievement? = nil
                
                // Find an existing achievement.
                thirtyAchievement = achievements?.first(where: { $0.identifier == thirtyID})
                
                // Otherwise, create a new achievement.
                if thirtyAchievement == nil {
                    thirtyAchievement = GKAchievement(identifier: thirtyID)
                }
                
                if score >= 30 {
                    thirtyAchievement?.showsCompletionBanner = true
                    thirtyAchievement?.percentComplete = 100
                }
                
                // Insert code to report the percentage.
                
                if error != nil {
                    // Handle the error that occurs.
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                }
                
                let fiftyID = "50"
                var fiftyAchievement: GKAchievement? = nil
                
                // Find an existing achievement.
                fiftyAchievement = achievements?.first(where: { $0.identifier == fiftyID})
                
                // Otherwise, create a new achievement.
                if fiftyAchievement == nil {
                    fiftyAchievement = GKAchievement(identifier: fiftyID)
                }
                
                if score >= 50 {
                    fiftyAchievement?.showsCompletionBanner = true
                    fiftyAchievement?.percentComplete = 100
                }
                
                // Insert code to report the percentage.
                
                if error != nil {
                    // Handle the error that occurs.
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                }
                
                let hundredID = "100"
                var hundredAchievement: GKAchievement? = nil
                
                // Find an existing achievement.
                hundredAchievement = achievements?.first(where: { $0.identifier == hundredID})
                
                // Otherwise, create a new achievement.
                if hundredAchievement == nil {
                    hundredAchievement = GKAchievement(identifier: hundredID)
                }
                
                if score >= 100 {
                    hundredAchievement?.showsCompletionBanner = true
                    hundredAchievement?.percentComplete = 100
                }
                
                // Insert code to report the percentage.
                
                if error != nil {
                    // Handle the error that occurs.
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                }
                
                let negativeID = "1"
                var negativeAchievement: GKAchievement? = nil
                
                // Find an existing achievement.
                negativeAchievement = achievements?.first(where: { $0.identifier == negativeID})
                
                // Otherwise, create a new achievement.
                if negativeAchievement == nil {
                    negativeAchievement = GKAchievement(identifier: negativeID)
                }
                
                if score < 0 {
                    negativeAchievement?.showsCompletionBanner = true
                    negativeAchievement?.percentComplete = 100
                }
                
                // Insert code to report the percentage.
                
                if error != nil {
                    // Handle the error that occurs.
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                }
                
                let clawID = "69"
                var clawAchievement: GKAchievement? = nil
                
                // Find an existing achievement.
                clawAchievement = achievements?.first(where: { $0.identifier == clawID})
                
                // Otherwise, create a new achievement.
                if clawAchievement == nil {
                    clawAchievement = GKAchievement(identifier: clawID)
                }
                
                if claw {
                    clawAchievement?.showsCompletionBanner = true
                    clawAchievement?.percentComplete = 100
                }
                
                // Insert code to report the percentage.
                
                if error != nil {
                    // Handle the error that occurs.
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                }
                
                let achievementsToReport: [GKAchievement] = [fifteenAchievement!, thirtyAchievement!, fiftyAchievement!, hundredAchievement!, clawAchievement!, negativeAchievement!]
                
                // Report the progress to Game Center.
                GKAchievement.report(achievementsToReport, withCompletionHandler: {(error: Error?) in
                    if error != nil {
                        // Handle the error that occurs.
                        print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                    }
                })
            })
        }
```

The `showCompletionBanner` property for all the achievements are true, so I have no idea why they are showing up. Here is my git repository if you want to take a look:

https://github.com/aabagdi/CursedSnake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! After resetting the achievements, I had to close and reopen the app. Given that the final version won't have the reset functionality, this won't be an issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Has the currently logged in player already earned this achievement? You can check with the `isCompleted` property.

Comment: I've tested this multiple times after resetting the achievements, and the notification doesn't pop up. It used to pop up, but no idea why it suddenly stopped.